# Python Pandas Iterate over rows and count how many times a unique pair of columns has shown

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a column to count the how many times a date at a station (No) has shown.

For example, Date 6/12/2013 show only 1 record at No1, so it is counted as 1. There are 3 records on 5/11/2013 at No 3. The first occurrence should count as 1, the second occurrence are counted as 2 and so on, and the third occurrence are counted as 3.

Input:

```
    No   Date        Value    
0   1    6/12/2013   35 
1   1    6/13/2013   45
2   1    6/14/2013   23
3   1    6/14/2013   40
4   2    6/12/2013   15
5   2    6/13/2013   20
6   2    6/14/2013   24
7   2    7/23/2013   33
8   3    5/11/2013   10
9   3    5/11/2013   11
10  3    5/11/2013   34
11  3    5/18/2013   24
.
.
.
```

The result should look like this:

```
    No   Date        Value    count
0   1    6/12/2013   35       1
1   1    6/13/2013   45       1
2   1    6/14/2013   23       1
3   1    6/14/2013   40       2
4   2    6/12/2013   15       1
5   2    6/13/2013   20       1
6   2    6/14/2013   24       1
7   2    7/23/2013   33       1
8   3    5/11/2013   10       1
9   3    5/11/2013   11       2
10  3    5/11/2013   34       3
11  3    5/18/2013   24       1
.
.
.
```

My own solution is

```
result = []
for n in df['No'].unique():
    df1 = df[df['No'] == n]
    for date in df1['Date'].unique():
        df2 = df1[df1['Date'] == date]
        df2['count'] = np.arange(len(df2)) + 1
        result.append(df2)
```

and merge the result together. But it runs pretty slow. Any better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['No', 'Date']).cumcount() + 1
```

Adding 1 in necessary since `cumcount` starts at 0.

The resulting output:

```
    No       Date  Value  count
0    1  6/12/2013     35      1
1    1  6/13/2013     45      1
2    1  6/14/2013     23      1
3    1  6/14/2013     40      2
4    2  6/12/2013     15      1
5    2  6/13/2013     20      1
6    2  6/14/2013     24      1
7    2  7/23/2013     33      1
8    3  5/11/2013     10      1
9    3  5/11/2013     11      2
10   3  5/11/2013     34      3
11   3  5/18/2013     24      1
```